# Plastic CSM make items Private/Ignored

Tags: unity-game-engine, plasticscm

Here I have some assets that don't want them to be pushed/pulled.
[image]

I don't want some assets and classes to be in controlled. and I want to make them as private Or ignored.
Simple Question. how can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by updated? Do you mean push any changes to your Git repo? If so add a `.gitignore` file with pointers to ignore those files to the repo

Comment: @akaBase yes that's what I mean. I don't want some items to be pushed, could you please give me some reference for how to do this cause I'm completely new at git subject.

Comment: [Docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) Sorry for the late reply, those are the docs if you haven't found them yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the items from source control (eg: via right-click -> Delete) while keeping the items in the workspace. After that, you can add the local items to the ignore list:
https://blog.plasticscm.com/2014/11/configuring-ignored-items-on-your.html